# How can I deselect one row in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have JTable with ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION:

```
 table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

When I use CTRL+mouse click, rows are selected and all are right. But if I want to deselect only one selected row and press CTRL+mouse click to one selected row, all rows are deselected, not only one. Then if I press CTRL+mouse click to some row again, previouse rows are selected again, but without row, that I wanted to deselect. 
I want to deselect only one row using CTRL+mouse click. How can I do that?

EDIT:
I had this in my code:

```
table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
```

I found that if I remove this line then all works fine. But can JTable work correctly although 'ColumnSelectionAllowed' is true?

Comment: this is not how JTable should work. Do you have any more code you can show? This behaviour is wrong.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Try method  `clearSelection` on  `JTable` .

it works by calling  `clearSelection  on the  ListSelectionModel`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for deselection one row from many, use the below code:

```
table.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionInterval(rowFrom, rowTo);
```

for deselecting one row:

```
table.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionInterval(row, row);
```

you can use multiple selection like this

```
table.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionInterval(1, 3); //1,2,3 starting from 0
table.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionInterval(5, 5); //5
```

to add it back, use:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(rowFrom, rowTo);
```

you can use multiple selection like this

```
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(1, 2); //1,2
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(4, 4); //4
```

to set it to specific range, which will clear your old selection first,

```
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(rowFrom, rowTo);
```

Which it is equal to:

```
table.clearSelection();
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(rowFrom, rowTo);
```